# Sylow subgroup of a subgroup of a finite nilpotent group is normal

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite nilpotent group and $H \le G$. Let $P$ be a Sylow subgroup of $H$. I'd like to either prove or disprove that, under these conditions, $P$ is normal in $H$.

Any hints how to get started?

(This is part of a larger proof that any subgroup of a nilpotent group is nilpotent.)

Comment: It depends on the definition of nilpotent you are using.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I'm using this definition: $G$ is nilpotent if its ascending central series has finite length. (Where *length* is the number of strict inclusions in the series.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof:** let $P$ be element of $Syl_p(H)$ then $P$ is an $p-$subgroup of $G$. Then it must be contained in a sylow-$p$ subgroup of $G$ .

Let say this is $Q$. We have $P≤Q\implies$  $P=H\cap{P}≤Q\cap{H}$ thus $Q\cap{H}$ is a $p-$subgroup of $H$ containing $P$.

By maximality of $P$ in $H$, $P=Q\cap{H}$. Now since $G$ is nilpotent then $Q$ is uniqe so is $P$.

Since $P$ is uniqe in $H$ then it is normal. By the way from that point, it is immediate that $H$ is nilpotent.